# Avoiding borders when printing on Canon Pro-10 with matte ink

Tags: canon, printing

The Canon Pro 10 uses two types of black ink - the PGI-72PBK for glossy paper and the PGI-72MBK for matte paper types.

Unfortunately the driver only uses the matte ink if fine art paper is selected - but then you also have to use the fine art size settings which require the printer to use a border of 30mm.

I spent quite some time searching the web if there was some kind of workaround to print with matte ink and also avoiding the borders.

The only solution i could find was to use an additional photo black cartridge filled with matte ink which is swapped with the original photo black ink when printing on matte papers.

Is this really the only way to trick the printer into using the whole paper surface when printing with matte ink or is there another solution which does not require to swap out the inks?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about printer management & settings, not photography.

Comment: Disagree on the vtc. This question is about producing a tangible print using a tool designed for photographers. That's on topic, IMO.

Comment: Bruno, are you attempting to print borderless?

Comment: I posted this question here because when searching stackexchange for possible answers, the best matches could be found in the photography forum.

I did not try to print borderless, but the fine art paper types which can be set in the printer driver require a 30mm border on top and bottom of the page - which is quite a waste of paper.

Comment: You need a printer that supports borderless printing. If the driver requires a border, the printer likely doesn't support borderless printing.

Comment: I think he would be happy with less than a 30mm border. That’s more than an inch off each side!

Comment: The printer does support borderless printing (for some media types) but that is not what i am looking for. I am looking for possibilities to print with the matte black ink - on third party papers - without the 30mm (1,18 inch) border. It is possible with the workaround described in my initial post, but it would be much easier if there was some solution which does not require to replace the ink cartridge.

Answer (score 1):

Generally printing to the edge causes problems with ink smearing, image quality at the edges, and on some printers can potentially (but unlikely) damage the print head. If you want a borderless image, just cut down the print.

Comment: Your right, and i understand canon to implement some restrictions to provide the best print quality and avoid damaging the printer. But it would be helpful for advanced users to be able to tweak at least some of the settings. Here the current drivers are very limiting. The PRO 10 is not a consumer device, it is targeted at advanced users.